# Logic gate - What will be the second input of each gate?

Tags: logic-gates

Full:

[image]

Cropped   :

[image]

In the second image (cropped) which is the same as the first (full) image... why the 1st Gate outputs "0"?

Comment: Will we get the marks for your homework? Show some effort. You can determine the output of one of the NAND gates.

Comment: I'm not schooling, this isn't a homework.

Comment: It really doesn't help that you changed the numbering of the gates between the two images.

Answer (score 1):

1st gate: the second input 1.
2nd gate: the second input 0.

Answer (score 1):

Gate 2 Output, regardless of its own Input A, will be 1.

[image]